# How to create custom common number-text comparer in C# to sort numeric/string list?

Tags: c#, sorting, icomparable

I have number-text list and I want to create common custom comparer logic to sort this list(s) using C#. E.g.

```
var numericList = new List<string>{"100", "--", "-0.98", "N/A", "0.00", "-888"};
var stringList = new List<string> {"Smith", "--", "Peter", "", "Jim", "Ken", "NA"};
```

which contains some special characters like --, N/A,Space etc. And expected result after sort will be - 
**For NemericList Ascending ->** N/A, -- , -888 , -0.98 , 0.00 , 100
**For StringList Ascending ->** Jim, Ken, N/A, Peter, Smith, Empty, --

I created following custom comparer logic which does some level of sorting but not matching with the expected result. Please suggest me the way to achieve this.

> ```
> public class NumberTextComparer : IComparer<string>
>     {
>         public int Compare(string s1, string s2)
>         {
>             double number1, number2;
>             var isS1Numeric = double.TryParse(s1, out number1);
>             var isS2Numeric = double.TryParse(s2, out number2);
>
>             if (isS1Numeric && isS2Numeric)
>             {
>                 if (number1 > number2) return 1;
>                 if (number1 < number2) return -1;
>                 return 0;
>             }
>
>             return isS1Numeric ? 1 : (isS2Numeric ? -1 : String.Compare(s1, s2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
>         }
>     }
> ```

```
var comparer = new NumberTextComparer();
var numericSortedListASC = numericList.OrderBy(str => str, comparer);
var stringSortedListASC = stringList.OrderBy(str => str, comparer);
```

Comment: what exactly isn't working about your comparer?

Comment: Sorting order is not coming as expected in both situations.

Comment: right, I meant what are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: For Numeric List I am getting -> --,N/A,-888 , -0.98 , 0.00 , 100 and For String List I am getting -> Empty,--, Jim, Ken, N/A, Peter, Smith

Comment: hmmm... aren't "--", "N/A" and "" equivalent?

Comment: Why would you expect Empty and "--" to be at the end? Forget for a while numerics, standard string comparison puts them at the beginning, not at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works correct. Se [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fI7QZh). Results:

```
--, N/A, -888, -0.98, 0.00, 100
, --, Jim, Ken, NA, Peter, Smith
```

The problem is your assumption, that the "" and "--" come after letters. Since they have a lower position in the [ascii-table](https://www.uni-due.de/hummell/infos/ascii/) they come first.

This would be a simple fix. Try [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fERS1t)

```
    public int Compare(string s1, string s2)
    {
        double number1, number2;
        var isS1Numeric = double.TryParse(s1, out number1);
        var isS2Numeric = double.TryParse(s2, out number2);

        if (isS1Numeric && isS2Numeric)
        {
            if (number1 > number2) return 1;
            if (number1 < number2) return -1;
            return 0;
        }
        if (isS1Numeric)
            return 1;
        if (isS2Numeric)
            return -1;

        bool s1StartsWithLetter = char.IsLetter(s1.FirstOrDefault());
        bool s2StartsWithLetter = char.IsLetter(s2.FirstOrDefault());

        if (s1StartsWithLetter == s2StartsWithLetter)
            return String.Compare(s1, s2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        return s1StartsWithLetter ? -1 : 1;
    }
```